# Building PETSc with Intel tools

Tags: intel, petsc

I would like to install PETSc library with Intel compilers, OpenMP, MPI, MKL. I am not sure how to properly create configure file. I have intel parallel studio xe 2017 installed on my computer. I checked ./configure --help in PETSc directory for options, but there is plenty of them. I don't how should I match it with [Intel-mkl-link-line-advisor](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor).
Anyone did this before?

Answer (score 2):

I use these build lines for my Intel build. Unfortunately I stumbled uppon your questio while trying to fix my own problem (which is probably caused by something else) but this build worked liek a charm for over 2 years.

Of course you'll have to change the PETSc dir to your source directory. The 'tee's are so that I can run a script that generates all the build I need (with differing compilers, MPI implementations, debug/opt, etc) and still have logs from each build on separete files.

```
./configure --with-cc=mpiicc --with-cxx=mpiicpc --with-fc=mpiifort --with-blas-lapack-dir=/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/ --with-debugging=1 PETSC_ARCH=linux-intel-dbg all test | tee linux-intel-dbg/configure.log
make PETSC_DIR=~/opt/petsc/ PETSC_ARCH=linux-intel-dbg all                                                                                                         | tee linux-intel-dbg/make.log
make PETSC_DIR=~/opt/petsc/ PETSC_ARCH=linux-intel-dbg test                                                                                                        | tee linux-intel-dbg/test.log
make PETSC_DIR=~/opt/petsc/ PETSC_ARCH=linux-intel-dbg streams NPMAX=8                                                                                             | tee linux-intel-dbg/streams.log
```